# what does eax have after mov eax,dword ptr [edi]

Tags: assembly

I have the following assembly code on Windows and I want to make sure that I understand correctly.
`edi` contains some address i.e. `0x6090F454`

In this case, what should `eax` have after the first `mov` instruction?

```
775672f3  mov eax,dword ptr [edi]

775672f5  mov dword ptr [ebp-50h],0 
775672fc  mov dword ptr [ebp-48h],0 

77567303  cmp eax,0FFFFFFFFh
```

It seems to me that `eax` must have the value but I am not so sure about that.
For your information, C++ code for the above assembly is

```
if (sem->num != INVALID_FLAG) {
    ....
}
```

Also, here is what's store in edi.

```
0:024> dd edi
6090f454  0c0e8fe0 ffffffff 00000000 00000000
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
mov eax,dword ptr [edi]
```

will simply load whatever is stored at the address `edi`. So it's a simple data load.

Since you don't show what is at address `edi` (`0x6090F434`), we can't tell you exactly what `eax` will be.

Based on the C++ code that is given, it looks like `edi` is the address of the `num` field. So it's reading `num` into a register, then comparing it against `0xFFFFFFFF` which is the `INVALID_FLAG` constant.

Comment: There was typo when I wrote edi. edi is actually 6090f454.
Here is what's stored in edi.

6090f454   0c0e8fe0 ffffffff 00000000 00000000

Comment: Wait, that doesn't make any sense, `edi` is only 32-bits. It can't store all of `6090f454 0c0e8fe0 ffffffff 00000000 00000000`. Is that just a register dump?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited the original question to be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that debugger, but assuming `0c0e8fe0 ffffffff 00000000 00000000` is the data pointed to by `edi`, then the instruction will load `0c0e8fe0` into `eax`. In other words, `sem->num = 0c0e8fe0`.

Answer (score 2):

EAX will contain the 32-bit value at 0x6090F434, assuming that address is 'exists' i.e. memory is assigned to your process at that address.

Which seems obvious, so I wonder if that's really what you want to know?

Comment: Yes, that's all I wanted to know. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a description to the assembly code posted by you:

```
mov eax,dword ptr [edi]
```

Move the value stored at memory address contained in the edi register to the eax register.

Your windbg output for the edi register shows:

6090f454  0c0e8fe0 ffffffff 00000000 00000000

The first value here is the memory address contained in the edi register. The next value, 0c0e8fe0 is the dword located at that memory address.

An easier way to understand and visualize would be:

```
dword ptr [edi] =  0c0e8fe0
dword ptr [edi+4] = ffffffff
dword ptr [edi+8] = 00000000
```

So, dd command is showing you the address in the first column and the dword data in the next 4 columns.

The assembly language instruction,

```
mov eax, dword ptr [edi]
```

will move the value 0c0e8fe0 into the eax register.

Similarly the next 2 instructions in your assembly language code will store the value 0 at the memory address pointed to by ebp-50 and ebp-48 respectively.

Usually, [ebp-4], [ebp-8] and so on, are used to reference the local variables in a program.

The last instruction,

```
cmp eax,0FFFFFFFFh
```

Compare the dword stored in eax register which is, 0c0e8fe0 with 0FFFFFFFFh. In this case, the values are not equal and so the Zero Flag will not be set.

Usually in assembly language code, a cmp instruction is followed by a conditional jump which checks a flag status.

So, you could have a jz or a jnz instruction following the cmp instruction.

Hope this helps you to make more sense out of the assembly language code.